# Multiply 1D-array by 1D-array or Constant - VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multiplication

At risk of being of topic, I decided to share some code, [Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). If the general opinion is such that this would be off-topic I'll be happy to delete if need be.

***<sub>Background:</sub>***

I've been wondering if it was possible to return a 1D-array from multiplying another 1D-array by either a constant value or a third 1D-array (of the same size) ***without*** iteration.

So the process I'm looking for would look like:

- Multiply by Constant > Derive `{3,6,9}` directly from `{1,2,3}*3`
- Multiply by array > Derive `{3,8,15}` directly from `{1,2,3}*{3,4,5}`

---

***<sub>Sample Code:</sub>***

I have seen questions regarding this topic, but I've not yet seen an answer that would do this without iteration. The closest I've seen is from @SiddharthRout, on an [external](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?611466-multiply-array-by-constant) forum.

But usually one would opt for iteration:

- Multiply by constant

```html
Sub Test()
    
    Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array(1,2,3)
    Dim y As Long, x As Long: x = 3 'Our constant
    
    For y = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        arr1(y) = arr1(y) * x
    Next y
    
    End Sub
```

- Multiply by array

```html
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3)
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Array(3, 4, 5)
Dim y As Long

For y = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    arr1(y) = arr1(y) * arr2(y)
Next y

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Question:</sub>***

How could you retrieve a 1D-array from multiplying another 1D-array by any constant or another (equally sized) 1D-array without iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of what I found was that the key to the answer would lay in `MMULT`, returning an array from multiplying rows*columns.

---

***<sub>Multiply 1D-Array by Constant</sub>***

```
Sub Multiply_1D_byConstant()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array(1, 4, 3, 5, 10, 15, 13, 11, 6, 9)

With Application

    Dim x As Long: x = 3 'Our constant
    Dim y As Long: y = UBound(arr1) + 1

    Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = .Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(" & x + 1 & ":" & x + y + 1 & ")-ROW(1:" & y + 1 & "))")
    Dim arr3 As Variant: arr3 = .Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & y & "))")
    Dim arr4 As Variant: arr4 = .Index(.MMult(.Transpose(arr1), arr2), arr3, 1)

End With

End Sub
```

Here, `.Evaluate` will quickly return a 1D-array n times our constant, n being `Ubound(arr1)+1`. In the above case: `{3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3}`

We than `.Transpose` arr1 within our `.MMult(.Transpose(arr1), arr2)` which will return a 2D-array. Because we would need to iterate that, we rather cut into the array to extract a 1D-array by `.Index`. The result of the above would be:

`{3, 12, 9, 15, 30, 45, 39, 33, 18, 27}`

To visualize how this works: `.MMult` will return a 2D-array from above example like so:

[image]

Then, because we basically give `.Index` an array like `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`, but in a dynamic way, for rows and just a 1 for the first column, `.Index` will slice a 1D-array out of this 2D-array:

[image]

---

***<sub>Multiply 1D-Array by 1D-Array</sub>***

This would work kind of the same. Let's imagine the below:

```
Sub Multiply_1D_by1D()

Dim arr1 As Variant: arr1 = Array(1, 4, 3, 5, 10, 15, 13, 11, 6, 9)
Dim arr2 As Variant: arr2 = Array(2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 1)

With Application

    Dim y As Long: y = UBound(arr1) + 1
    Dim arr3 As Variant: arr3 = .Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & y & "))")
    Dim arr4 As Variant: arr4 = .Index(.MMult(.Transpose(arr1), arr2), arr3, arr3)

End With

End Sub
```

This time we don't tell `.Index` to extract the same, constant, first column from the result of `.MMult`, but we give it the same array of values as the rows. These values need to be a 1D-array so therefor we use the `.Evaluate` to return the array dynamically. So the above returns a 1D-array like:

`{2, 4, 12, 5, 20, 45, 26, 55, 12, 9}`

To visualize how this works: `.MMult` will return a 2D-array from above example like so:

[image]

Then, because we basically give `.Index` two arrays like `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`, but in a dynamic way, `.Index` will slice a 1D-array out of this 2D-array:

[image]

---

In this same fashion you can slice out any 1D-array from a 2D-array using `.Index` as long as you both specify the rows and columns parameter with a valid 1D-array. I hope this will be helpfull to anyone.

Comment: First one could be simplified to `arr4 = .Transpose(.MMult(.Transpose(arr1), Array(x)))`. Maybe it would also be worth adding a note: _it is possible and it works but never ever use it in production, or else you can kill performance_:)

Comment: I suppose this could be heavy on performance @Braknicku. I actually haven't done any testing but I'm sure it can be "killing".