# Efficient multiplication in VBA with macros

Tags: excel, vba, math

I am trying to create a code that is as **efficient** as possible.

What I need to do is **Multiply a range** of cells by a fixed value and then replace the value that each cell had with that new value.

For example:

In the "D5: 25" range I have different numerical values in each of the cells. Then I multiply each cell by a fixed value and that new value is replaced in each cell (I mean in the range "D5: 25").

I was able to solve it through two ways, but both are **"inefficient"**, since when I run the code it shows that it takes a long time to perform all the multiplication in that range.

And also as I then need to do the same in other ranges too, I know that this code will not be efficient because it will take a long time.

I pass the two codes that **do work** but are **inefficient**.

**Code 1:**

```
Sub dolartopesos()
'Routine to pass to pesos all the prices of the products of each supplier that are in dollars.

dollars = Worksheets(3).Range("R1")

'---------------------------------------------------

With Worksheets(3)
'Currency exchange

For i = 5 To 25

.Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(i, 4) * dollars

Next i


End With


'---------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```

**Code2:**

```
Sub dolartopesos()
'Routine to pass to pesos all the prices of the products of each supplier that are in dollars.

dollars = Worksheets(3).Range("R1")

'---------------------------------------------------
''Currency exchange

Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Worksheets(3).Range("D5:25")
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng.Cells
With cel
cel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Product(cel, dollars)
End With
Next cel

'---------------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Both codes take too long to multiply in that range.

What could I do to **speed up** the multiplication?

Any contribution will be welcome. From already thank you very much.

Comment: The usual way of speeding up such calculations is to copy the excel ranges to a VBA array, do the operation on the array, then write the array back to excel.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59643944/9758194) you can find an example to multiply an array by a constant.

Comment: For each is always faster than your Code1 loop. Also, with for each loop, you don't need the With cel and End With lines.

Answer (score 1):

`Evaluate` works with array references and returns an array which can be assigned directly to the range you're working with:

```
With Worksheets(3).Range("D5:D25")
    .Value = .Parent.Evaluate("=" & .address() & "*" & dollars)
End With
```

Comment: I dont know how, but when i ran the code the vba debugger show me an error. And all the cells turn to "error value". I tried with this code and works properly and fast.     With Sheets(3)

        .[D5:D25] = .[D5:D25*S1]
        .[F5:F25] = .[F5:F25*S1]
        .[H5:H25] = .[H5:H25*S1]
        .[J5:J25] = .[J5:J25*S1]
        .[L5:L25] = .[L5:L25*S1]

    End With

Comment: I copied your typo "D5:25" should be "D5:D25"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying to an array you could use this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestIt()

    Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range
    Dim val As Double
    val = 2

    Set rg1 = Range("D5:D25")
    Set rg2 = rg1.Offset(0, 1) ' or any other free range of the same size

    TurnOffFunctionality
    rg2.Formula = "=RC[-1]*" & val  ' Adjust formula accordingly
    rg1.Value = rg2.Value
    rg2.Clear
    TurnOnFunctionality

End Sub



' Procedure : TurnOffFunctionality
' Source    : www.TheExcelVBAHandbook.com
' Author    : Paul Kelly
' Purpose   : Turn off automatic calculations, events and screen updating
Private Sub TurnOffFunctionality()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

' Procedure : TurnOnFunctionality
' Source    : www.TheExcelVBAHandbook.com
' Author    : Paul Kelly
' Purpose   : turn on automatic calculations, events and screen updating
Private Sub TurnOnFunctionality()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If this is faster then using arrays I did not test but it should be faster than your original approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this code and works properly and fast.
' S1 is the cell that contain the value of dollars.

```
With Sheets(3)

        .[D5:D25] = .[D5:D25*S1]
        .[F5:F25] = .[F5:F25*S1]
        .[H5:H25] = .[H5:H25*S1]
        .[J5:J25] = .[J5:J25*S1]
        .[L5:L25] = .[L5:L25*S1]

End With
```